# Apache2.4.6 Webdav not working on Centos7

Tags: apache, centos7, webdav

I have installed Apache 2.4.6 on Centos7 official.
httpd.conf was not changed from default.
Configured webdav.conf with the following:

```
DavLockDB /var/www/html/DavLock
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/webdav/
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access.log combined
    Alias /webdav /var/www/html/webdav
    <Directory /var/www/html/webdav>
        DAV On
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

webdav directory has 755 rights. DavLock not created.

I keep getting this error and not sure what the cause might be. Have tried many things without success:
[Fri Jan 29 11:41:17.027110 2021] [dav:error] [pid 15068] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53946] The locks could not be queried for verification against a possible "If:" header.  [500, #0]
[Fri Jan 29 11:41:17.027134 2021] [dav:error] [pid 15068] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53946] Could not open the lock database.  [500, #400]
[Fri Jan 29 11:41:17.027137 2021] [dav:error] [pid 15068] (13)Permission denied: [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53946] Could not open property database.  [500, #1]

any ideas are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working now.
all files/folders under /var/www/ are chown to apache

```
moved DavLock to here: /var/lib/dav/
```

and added this line under httpd.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
    # Location of the WebDAV lock database.
    DAVLockDB /var/lib/dav/DavLock
</IfModule>
```

At this point, I am getting 403 error. Solved by executing the following:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t /var/www/html/webdav/
```